# C# UserControl Visible Property

Tags: c#, compact-framework, properties, components, visible

How can I override a `UserControl` `Visible` property ? Or how could I determine within a control when it changes its `Visible` state ?

Later edit: I need it to work in .NET CF 3.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue by adding a `new Visible` property which is setting the `base.Visible` property and does my custom work.

Comment: That's that way to do it. Accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to subscribe to the [IsVisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onvisiblechanged.aspx) event

Comment: It looks to me this is not supported in the CF version.